# For loop printing twice sometimes

Tags: java

In my convertEuro method the for loop is causing the output to be printed twice,  but only sometimes. What I mean is this is what gets displayed:

```
Converting values to Euros.
£4.00 >>> €5.45
£123.44 >>> €168.13
Converting values to Euros.
£4.00 >>> €5.45
£123.44 >>> €168.13
```

During testing it seems to do this maybe 2 times out of 10, and I can't figure out why. Code below if someone can please help:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Conversion {

    public void mainMenu(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values, DecimalFormat twoDecimal) {

        int menuChoice;

        System.out.println("1. Enter values and type -1 to stop");
        System.out.println("2. Euros");
        System.out.println("3. Dollars");
        System.out.println("4. Yen");
        System.out.println("5. Rupees");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");

        menuChoice = scan.nextInt();

        switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:

            enterValues(scan, values, twoDecimal);

        case 2:

            scan.nextLine();
            convertEuro(scan, values, twoDecimal);

        }

    }

    public void enterValues(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values, DecimalFormat twoDecimal) {
        double value = 0;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter value. Enter -1 to stop: £");



            while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a double (£xx.xx): £");
                scan.nextLine(); //Consumes \n
                scan.next();
            }

            value = scan.nextDouble();

            if (value != -1) {
                values.add(value);
                System.out.println("Value entered.");
            }

        }
        while (value != -1);


        System.out.println("Returning to main menu. ");
        mainMenu(scan, values, twoDecimal);

    }

    public void convertEuro(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values, DecimalFormat twoDecimal) {

        System.out.println("Converting values to Euros.");

        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("£" + twoDecimal.format(values.get(i)) + " >>> " + "\u20ac" + twoDecimal.format(values.get(i) * 1.362));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Conversion conv = new Conversion();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
        DecimalFormat twoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        conv.mainMenu(scan, values, twoDecimal);

        scan.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add "break;" statements in your "case" blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `break;` statement:

```
case 1:
    enterValues(scan, values, twoDecimal);
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

When the `switch` statement hits the correct case, it executes it and proceeds executing other cases which are below until and unless it hit an `break` statement.

The correct process is

```
 switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:
            enterValues(scan, values, twoDecimal);
            break;
        case 2:
            scan.nextLine();
            convertEuro(scan, values, twoDecimal);
            break;
        }
```

Thats why best practice is to put break statement after every case end.

Thank you